# omp C code -- loop process slows to a crawl with added threads

Tags: memory, openmp

I've pored over lots of stack overflow posts trying to figure out what's going on in my program, but to no avail.  I have an algorithm that I think is a great candidate for parallelization.  That algorithm is contained within a function call, which is wrapped in a single for loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(fci, weightSet, numWeightSets, i)
    {
#pragma omp for 
        for(i = 0; i < numWeightSets; i++) {
            fci->results[i] = runWeightSet(fci, weightSet[i]);
        }
    }
```

- fci is a big struct with some time-series data embedded within
- every call of runWeightSet() uses a different set of weights, contained in weightSet[i]
- the first thing runWeightSet() does is to allocate space for the product of the time-series data and the weightSet[i] data along with a bunch of intermediary variables; the time-series data is read by all threads, but
- that part happens pretty fast in all threaded scenarios
- a nested loop is then entered in which there are a lot of computations and read/writes to the allocated memory but only to that memory and no more reads from the common time-series data are done.

On our 64-core machine, I get the following approximate average run times for runWeightSet() (N=number of cores, seconds=ave runtime):
**N seconds**
1   230
2   240
4   250
8   260
11  270
16  300
32  1200
64  9000

My suspicion is that I've got some sort of memory read/write bottleneck that gets crippling when I add lots of CPU cores.  I've tried running perf on it but am not quite sure what to make of the output.  Any ideas or suggestions would be most appreciated.
-Jim

Comment: It is hard to provide you a proper answer with the little information currently available. Please add additional ones, like the number of iterations, the type of processor, the type of the of the structure, the compiler used, the content of `runWeightSet`. Such information can have a drastic impact on the resulting timings. Also consider providing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just a simple question: why do you declare `i` as `shared`? What makes you believe this is a good idea?

Comment: @Gilles, originally I didn't have the outer `#pragma`.  I added it because I had seen examples that used it and have no strong convictions about making `i` shared or private, though it seems to have not made any difference.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, the compiler is gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) and /proc/cpuinfo says there are 64 AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX 32-Core Processors.  I'm afraid it's not practical to include the fci struct or the code as they're pretty large.  The included loop currently gets called 3003 times and the loop inside `runWeightSet()` goes through about 1.3 million iterations.  All computations inside that loop -- which is where the real time is spent -- involve only variables local to the function, either declared or alloc'd.

Comment: Another thing that caught my attention is that the machine is set up with 128Gb of RAM and 0 swap.  Don't know if this is common when setting up containers like this one.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is inside `runWeightSet`. Maybe you can make a smaller version of the code with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem why it scales so badly is likely inside the `runWeightSet` method, but we won't know until you show it to us ;).

However, try deleting the first #pragma and replace the second one with `#pragma omp parallel for`. The `i` should definitely not be shared, you will have race conditions occurring frequently as threads try to increase it and use it for accessing the weighted sets. It needs to be local (ensured by using the omp `for`construct. So maybe this makes `runWeightSet` misbehave.

Comment: thanks -- I ditched the enclosing `#pragma` a couple of days ago.  I'm going to try a few things today...